# Insert HTML after each table row using variables from that row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, confluence

Could you help me out with this?

I have a table like this:

```
     <table>
     <th style="text-align: left; text-transform: capitalize;">Unique</th>
     <th style="text-align: left; text-transform: capitalize;">x1</th>
     <th style="text-align: left; text-transform: capitalize;">y2</th>
     <tr class="rowNormal">
     <td nowrap="true">a1</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b2</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="rowAlternate">
     <td nowrap="true">a1</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b2</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="rowNormal">
     <td nowrap="true">a1</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b2</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b3</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

What I need to do is insert certain HTML after each `tr`, using the value of the last `td` in that `tr` to populate a variable inside that HTML.
I.e. the code above should look like:

```
     <table>
     <th style="text-align: left; text-transform: capitalize;">Unique</th>
     <th style="text-align: left; text-transform: capitalize;">x1</th>
     <th style="text-align: left; text-transform: capitalize;">y2</th>
     <tr class="rowNormal">
     <td nowrap="true">a1</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b2</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b3</td>
     </tr>
     <p>
     <ac:macro ac:name="mymacro">
     <ac:parameter ac:name="content">titles</ac:parameter>
     <ac:parameter ac:name="labels">+VALUE_TD +othervalue</ac:parameter>
     </ac:macro>
     </p>
     <tr class="rowAlternate">
     <td nowrap="true">a1</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b2</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b3</td>
     </tr>
     <p>
     <ac:macro ac:name="mymacro">
     <ac:parameter ac:name="content">titles</ac:parameter>
     <ac:parameter ac:name="labels">+VALUE_TD +othervalue</ac:parameter>
     </ac:macro>
     </p>
     <tr class="rowNormal">
     <td nowrap="true">a1</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b2</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b3</td>
     </tr>
     <p>
     <ac:macro ac:name="mymacro">
     <ac:parameter ac:name="content">titles</ac:parameter>
     <ac:parameter ac:name="labels">+VALUE_TD +othervalue</ac:parameter>
     </ac:macro>
     </p>
     </table>
```

In this example, `VALUE_TD` will equal b3 for all 3 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using the jQuery function `insertAfter`.

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pSwkM/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($('tr'), function (i, row) {
        if (i != 0) {
            var lastTd = $(row).find('td:last-child')[0];
            $('<p>\
<ac:macro ac:name="mymacro">\
<ac:parameter ac:name="content">titles</ac:parameter>\
<ac:parameter ac:name="labels">' + lastTd.innerHTML + 'othervalue</ac:parameter>\
</ac:macro>\
</p>').insertAfter(row);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is another example using the jQuery function `after`, both work they are just different ways of doing it.

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pSwkM/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each($('tr'), function (i, row) {
        if (i != 0) {
            var lastTd = $(row).find('td:last-child')[0];
            $(row).after('<p>\
<ac:macro ac:name="mymacro">\
<ac:parameter ac:name="content">titles</ac:parameter>\
<ac:parameter ac:name="labels">' + lastTd.innerHTML + 'othervalue</ac:parameter>\
</ac:macro>\
</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

I would also like to say that this isn't valid HTML for a few reasons:

- The `<th>`'s should be wrapped in a `<tr>`.
- The `<p>` tags are not valid inside a `<table>` tag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. But does it take last td's as VALUE_TD ?

Comment: I just realised you want the data inserted from the td's I'll fix up the example to do that :)

Comment: Updated, the value from the last td will come through now.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a bunch. I'll get back after testing that. If it works, it will save me a lot of manual work.

Comment: No problems, let me know if there are any other problems. I encourage you to fix up the validity issues though as they can cause problems with displaying and assistive technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Create one div after each `tr` like  `<div id="tr1">  </div>`

By using jquery you can append html script

```
$('#tr1').append('your script');
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could append scripts. Unfortunately, the table is plugin-generated, so I only can insert divs using jquery.